# SQL allowing an entity to participate in a relationship only if it meets certain requirements

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I have a practice Super Hero SQL database with a SuperPerson table and a Disaster table. There are two relationships between SuperPerson and Disaster, Create and Prevent. The SuperPerson table has a Disposition column that tells us if they are evil or good. How can I make it so that only a SuperPerson that is good can participate in the Prevent relationship and vice versa for the Create relationship?

I've thought about creating two new tables, SuperHero and SuperVillian that reference the SuperPerson table, is this the most logical thing to do or is there some PL/SQL that I can use to enforce this constraint?

Edit: [Here's a link to a schema of the database so far](https://github.com/JCass45/Superhero-DB/blob/master/superhero-db.pdf)

Comment: If only certain members can participate in a relationship, that is a good indication that your data model is conflating two different types of entities. The PL/SQL required to enforce the constraint will usually be more complex than simply having two tables.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp This is true, but in this context I would be splitting SuperPerson into SuperHero and SuperVillian, which would have little to no difference. Is this a waste of tables?

Comment: you can query for good `SuperPerson` while creating a `Prevent` relationship and vice-versa for `Create`. Why do you want to put a constraint at the entity level?

Comment: There's no such thing as "wasting" tables - your design should have no more, and no fewer, than the number of tables required for the design to be correct. If you need tables for SuperHeroes, SuperVillains, and SuperPersons, create them.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal would be to define the foreign key as:

```
add constraint fk_disaster_create
    foreign key (create, 'good') references superperson (superpersonid, disposition);
```

Unfortunately, constants are not allowed for such references.  One method is to define a fixed column with the two values:

```
alter table disaster add disposition_good varchar2(255) default 'good';
alter table disaster add disposition_evil varchar2(255) default 'evil';

alter table disaster add constraint fk_disaster_create
    foreign key (create, 'good') references superperson (superpersonid, disposition);
```

Comment: Could I use a trigger to check if the Disposition of a SuperPerson being entered is good/evil and throw an error if not?

Comment: @JackCassidy . . . Of course, you can use triggers instead.

Comment: Is it possible to check the value of an attribute in a table other than the one the trigger is referring to? For example, when a row gets inserted into the HeroDisaster table, can I ask for the value of Disposition in the SuperPerson table with the corresponding SuperID?